# One function switching on type vs Many typed functions

Tags: performance, types, go

Given the following struct `Foo` and goal of handling multiple types (where `Handle` could be `Read`, `Write`, etc.). I understand that we lose compile-time type checks when we use the empty interface, though aside from this, what are the pros and cons of each? Finally, what is the most idiomatic way to achieve this?

```
package main

type Foo struct {
    A int
    B string
}

//Handle all types with switch
func (f *Foo) Handle(obj interface{}) {

    switch obj := obj.(type) {
    case int:
        //do int stuff...
        f.A + obj
    case string:
        //do string stuff...
        f.B + obj
    default:
        panic("Unknown type")
    }
}

//Handle each type individually
func (f *Foo) HandleInt(i int) {
    //do int stuff...
    f.A + i
}
func (f *Foo) HandleString(s string) {
    //do string stuff...
    f.B + s
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty interface is necessary if you're going to handle user-defined types via `reflect`. That's `fmt.Printf`, `json.Encode`, and `binary.Write`'s reason for accepting it. In terms of the [Merkle tree scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495896/implementing-a-merkle-tree-data-structure-in-go) you posted about earlier, where you're hashing things, you'd use an empty interface if your `Hash()` had a `reflect`-based fallback for hashing user-created structs.

Specific methods probably make more sense if you're only going to provide methods for a few key types (`[]byte`, `string`, whatever). Besides compile-time checking, the function list serves as documentation of what you can hash. On the other hand, if there are, like, a dozen-plus types you want to hash--think all the (u)int types and slices of them--I think I'd use an `interface{}` just for the sake of an uncluttered API unless you absolutely needed the very best performance, but I don't think there's a clear consensus one way or the other.

Comment: Yep, the number of [u]int types is what was troubling me actually. I wasn't looking forward to having a method per builtin type. Aesthetically, I'd prefer to have one method and document it well. Also, maybe including 3 specific methods and 1 generic method (both approaches) would confuse the user.

Answer (score 1):

One good example would be the [package sort](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/) ([sources here](http://golang.org/src/pkg/sort/sort.go)), which:

- does implement one method for basic type (as in your second approach)
- proposes an [interface](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) that the type to be sorted has to implement.
- can sort slices and user-defined collection

If you do the same for `Handle(obj interface{})` => `Handle(obj Interface)`, that would help you handler (for more complex type) to be defined once, using the methods declared in '`Interface`'.
Any type satisfying said `Interface` would be passed to the generic `Handle()` function.
And you could Handle slice (similar to [this example for `sort`](http://golang-examples.tumblr.com/post/66101563407/sort-a-slice)) or used-defined collection as well.

Comment: Thanks for the examples - that's a nice pattern, though I want to be able to handle built-in types (all the types of [u]ints) so I think I'll go with @twotwotwo's answer.